# How to store Huffman's transformed binary code?

Tags: c++, bit, huffman-code

I have one example:

```
string str = "01100111 011011 011 0110011011 0111101 "
```

There is no data type to hold a bit.

First, i dynamically allocate three bytes;

```
BYTE* store = new BYTE[3];
```

Second, put the binary code <- i can't code this.

Third, if it is larger than the specified size, it is increased by 3 bytes.

How do i code it?

Comment: Check bitwise shift operators

Comment: Look into using `std::bitset`.

Comment: you just want to look at one character at a time, in reverse, for a string.  This means you want to look into `std::string::rbegin()`

Comment: Why do you allocate 3 bytes? And not, say, 5?

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

## 1) Use a `std::vector<bool>`

This is probably the most C++-like way of doing it. The `std::vector` is specialized for `bool`s, where it stores each boolean as a bit. It also allocates memory for you, so you don't have to worry about resizing the vector if there are more bits.

There is a downside of having to go through a reference class to access the bits directly, and using bitwise operators with a `std::vector<bool>` is a bit awkward.

## 2) Bitwise shift operators

C++ also has the operators `<<`, `>>`, `<<=`, and `>>=` that can be used to move bits. The `<<` operator shifts all of the bits to the left, and `>>` shifts them to the right. `<<=` and `>>=` are to `<<` and `>>`, like `+=` is to `+`.

Here is an example of them:

```
unsigned char bits = 0b10010010 // uses binary literal syntax
bits <<= 1 // each bit in the variable is shifted left by one, making
           // the bits be `00100100`. Note that the overflow is ignored.

bits >>= 2 // bits is now `00001001`
```

You can use these in conjunction with the AND and OR operators (`|` and `&`) to manipulate bits.

Also, while this doesn't perfectly solve your problem alone, you also use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) to represent bits. You'll still have to use the bitwise shift operators though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a datatype `std::bitset` in the standard library; unfortunately, it's size needs to be a `constexpr`, such that you can't define it dynamically (e.g. depending on the size of your content / string).

A way to achieve the behaviour you want is to use `std::vector<bool>`:

```
int main() {
    string str = "01100111 011011 011 0110011011 0111101 ";

    //bitset<70> bits(str); // requires 70 as constexpr

    vector<bool> bits;
    for (auto c : str) {
        if (c=='1')
            bits.push_back(true);
        else if (c=='0')
            bits.push_back(false);
        else {
            // ignore
        }
    }

    for (auto bit : bits) {
        cout << bit;
    }

}
```

Note that datatype `vector<bool>` may be optimized for speed/memory consumption, but it does not have to be (cf., for example, [cppreference.com - vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)):

> The manner in which std::vector is made space efficient (as well
>   as whether it is optimized at all) is implementation defined.